# How to access dynamically added check boxes in another page event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

Any one can help...
I need to access dynamically added checkboxes in other events   I will share my code

```
void bindMaterials()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        SqlCommand FCimsbindoptCommand = Con.CreateCommand();
        FCimsbindoptCommand.Connection = Con;
        FCimsbindoptCommand.CommandText = "select * from nhcms_privilege";

        SqlDataAdapter FCimsSrchAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(FCimsbindoptCommand);
        DataTable FCimsSrchDataSet = new DataTable();
        FCimsSrchAdapter.Fill(FCimsSrchDataSet);

        int rowcount = FCimsSrchDataSet.Rows.Count;

        var a = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in FCimsSrchDataSet.Rows)
            {
                a.Add(row["Privilege_Name"].ToString());
            }
            string[] strdata = a.ToArray();

            foreach (var value in a)
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
                checkbox.ID = "chk" + value;
                checkbox.Text = value;

                Panel1.Controls.Add(checkbox);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I want to access these check box controls into button event

Comment: Where are you calling `bindMaterials()` it obviously needs to be before you try and access their values. Other than that it should just be a matter of `Panel1.FindControl("ControlId")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675142/asp-net-cannot-access-to-dynamically-created-controls/26675340#26675413

Comment: If they're a list (it appears to be based on your code), you could just use a CheckboxList, get the control then iterate the items in it to find whether they're checked or not.

Comment: Now every thing is working... but can not accessing check box id in other event calling from other event not in page load..