# asp.net cannot access to dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating 5 radio button when my page is loading :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                RadioButton r = new RadioButton();
                r.Text = i.ToString();
                r.ID = i.ToString(); ;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(r);

            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to access them in another method correspond to a click button, but I cannot. :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)FindControl("2");
        r.Checked = true;             
    }
```

When I am doing my findcontrol method, I get the following exception : nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code

Comment: But I don't understand how I can access to my radio buttons created in page_load method.

Comment: @SonerGönül The question has a specific problem. "How to access dynamic controls". The answer should contain the details related to this problem. The question you marked as duplicate doesn't completely answer the question.

Comment: Ok, I reopened your question since it is not entirely related to `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: If you ONLY create the controls on non-postback, they won't be available during a postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindControl` does not do deep search. You added radio buttons to `Panel1`, but calling `FindControl` of `Page`.

```
RadioButton r = (RadioButton)Panel1.FindControl("2");
```

Another thing. Remove `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` condition. When `Button1_Click` fires, the page is in PostBack state and dynamic controls have to be created if you expect to find them.

Comment: There is another function that goes deeper recursively but you wont need that. I think that Igor has the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the controls in the `Panel1`, so you should find it in there.

Replace the line:

```
RadioButton r = (RadioButton)FindControl("2");
```

with:

```
RadioButton r = Panel1.FindControl("2") as RadioButton;
if(r != null)  //check for null reference, before accessing
    r.Checked = true;
```

Comment: ok, and I also have to remove the if postback condition in my page_load method isn't it?

Comment: Yes you need to remove it if you don't want to lose your controls on post back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that is controls are created or not and  need to check null value. You are doing it  a wrong way. To solve this error First check object is initialized or not if it is Initialized that means value is not received by reference variable. Please check the following link for reference:
http://blog.mastersoftwaresolutions.com/why-null-reference-error-occurred/